# How do i achieve my desired output using fork() in c using linux?

Tags: c, linux

I understand that a program can fork several times. I also understand that each child process can use fork to spawn children of its own. Im trying to write a program which creates two subprocesses, each subprocess should then create one sub process of its own. This is my desired output:

```
 I'm the child '7786' parent '7785'
 I'm the sub-child '7787' parent '7786'
 I'm the second child: '7788' parent: '7785'
 I'm the second sub-child: '7789' parent: '7788'
```

here is my code. When I had forks() the output gets all weird and i dont know how to deal with it

```
int pid, ppid;
pid =getpid();
ppid = getppid();
printf("I'm the child: %d \t Parent process id:%d\n", pid, ppid);
printf("I'm the sub-child: %d \t Parent process id:%d\n", pid, ppid);
printf("I'm the second child: %d \t Parent process id:%d\n", pid, ppid);
printf("I'm the second sub-child: %d \t Parent process id:%d\n", pid, ppid);

return 0;
```

Comment: You'll probably want some `fork()` calls in there.

Comment: I know, but when I put them, the output gets all weird

Comment: You have to show us what you actually tried, and the "weird" output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you I think you want. I would have a better idea if you showed us the weird output as @Jim Garrison suggested. I think you're output would have come from your not waiting for children to terminate. You have no control over which process the OS allows to operate on the CPU at what time. So if I did not have the `wait(&status)` commands below, the output could come out in any order. By having the `wait` commands it forces the parent to wait for it's children to finish before it continues. So the below code will output what you want it the order you specified in your question.

If you want to see how you can't control the order of execution, remove the `wait` commands and run the program several times. The output should appear in a random order.

```
int pid1, pid2, subpid1, subpid2, status;
pid1 = fork();

if (pid1 == 0) {
    /* First child */
    printf("I'm the child: %d \t Parent process id:%d\n", getpid(), getppid());

    subpid1 = fork();
    if (subpid1 == 0) {
        /* First sub-child */
        printf("I'm the sub-child: %d \t Parent process id:%d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    } else {
        wait(&status); /* Wait until sub-child terminates */
    }

} else {
    wait(&status); /* Wait until child terminates */

    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 == 0) {
        /* Second child */
        printf("I'm the second child: %d \t Parent process id:%d\n", getpid(), getppid());

        subpid2 = fork();
        if (subpid2 == 0) {
            /* Second sub-child */
            printf("I'm the second sub-child: %d \t Parent process id:%d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        } else {
            wait(&status); /* Wait until second sub-child terminates */
        }
    } else {
        wait(&status); /* Wait until second child terminates */
    }
}

return 0;
```